# Print fixed number of characters per line in perl

Tags: perl, printing

Suppose I have a string of length 160 characters and I want to print it out to a file with 30 characters per line (so the 5 first line in the output will have 30 characters and the last line will have 10 characters).

Is there a straight forward perl command for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearer and more concise using [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)

```
my $s = join('', 'A' .. 'J') x 16;

print "$_\n" for unpack '(A30)*', $s;
```

**output**

```
ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ
ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ
ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ
ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ
ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

Answer (score 3):

You can insert newlines every 30 chars,

```
$string =~ s/.{1,30}\K/\n/sg;
```

or using variation of @Miller solution,

```
while ($string =~ m/(.{1,30})/gs) {
  print $1, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex, taking advantage of greedy matching:

```
my $string = 'a' x 160;

for my $buffer ($string =~ m/.{1,30}/gs) {
    print $buffer, "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Split into groups of 30 or less, then join with newline:

```
$string = join("\n", ( $string =~ m/.{1,30}/g ));
```

Answer (score 0):

[There's more than one way to do it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)! :-)

For this task I would reach for [`Perl6::Form`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6%3a%3aForm), a very powerful text formatting library. The Perl6 namespace implies that it's a back-port of a Perl 6 feature to Perl 5.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Perl6::Form;

my $s = join('', 'A' .. 'J') x 16;

say form "{" . ("[" x 30) . "}", $s;
```

This outputs:

```
$ ./line-breaks.pl
ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJA-
BCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJAB-
CDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABC-
DEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCD-
EFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDE-
FGHIJ
```

Note the "-" characters on the end of each line. This shows that `Perl6::Form` actually handles word breaking unlike the `unpack()`- or `m//g`-based solutions.

For example if we give it some text with spaces in it we can see it is left-aligned, with a ragged right edge.

```
$ ./line-breaks.pl
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut...
```

If you change the 30 `"["` characters to 15 `"["` characters followed by 15 `"]"` characters then you get fully justified output.

```
$ ./line-breaks.pl
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit   amet,
consectetur  adipisicing   elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut...
```

Like I said, [`Perl6::Form`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6%3a%3aForm) is very powerful :-)

You will need to install it, either via CPAN (`/usr/bin/cpan`) or your OS' package manager. On Debian you can install `Perl6::Form` system-wide with `sudo apt-get install libperl6-form-perl`.